# How to match data from different table equals to one of multiple values in ms excel

Tags: excel, multivalue

I have two tables in ms.excel 2010.
Said that tableA:

```
nodeID   value
A1R      ?
Akt      ?
Camk     ?
```

tableB:

```
Symbol  AliasName
A1Rt    A1RtA,a1R
Akt1    Akt,Rac
Pnck    Camk1
```

How to match data from tableA and tableB with that kind of values?
1. If nodeID is same or similar to Symbol, the value becomes 1
2. If nodeID is same or similar to AliasName, the value also becomes 1

So the results will be:

```
nodeID   value
A1R      1
Akt      1
Camk     1
```

I'm using vlookup like this but cannot find the exact result:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2=(VLOOKUP(A2,data!$F$1:$I$4351,1,FALSE)),1,0),0)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following formula with the setup as per image below

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(A7,$A$2:$B$4),0)),1,0)
```

To work, this must be entered as an array formula. To do this enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and after doing so you will see curly brackets around it - `{}`

The formula essentially tries to find your string in any cell (**Symbol** or **AliasName**) and if it's found it returns a 1, otherwise a 0.

Note that the `FIND` function is case sensitive and requires the whole **NodeID** to be found within the **Symbol** or **AliasName** fields. This means that `Camk` would be found in a string such as `Camk1` but not `Cam`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your example is working! I don't know we can use find instead of vlookup. But SUM here why should we use?

Comment: When you use Ctrl+shift+enter the `IFERROR(FIND(A7,$A$2:$B$4),0)` returns an array of zeros and the numeric positions were your string has been found. The `SUM` sums that array. If it returns positive it means that the string has been found at least once.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thank you for your explanation. I understand now.